# Accessing a variable outside a given function

Tags: swift, variables, completion

I tried the completion handler as suggested by Gurdev and got something. It does return the values of my array in the MAIN function. But the issue is the same: I have to use Sleep() function for 3 seconds for the HTTP request to complete. This is like hard coding as it could take less or more than 3 seconds to complete. When I remove the Sleep() command, I end up returning a VOID array.

The relevant code is pated below.

Thanks!

```
  --------Web Class--------
  import Foundation
  import UIKit

  class Web {

      var ar1 = [Double]()

      var ar2 = [Double]()

      func getData(str: String, completion: (_ result: [[Double]]) -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: str)!)

    httpGet(request as URLRequest!){
        (data, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "Error")
        } else {
            let delimiter = "\t"
            let lines:[String] = data.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines) as [String]

        for line in lines {
                var values:[String] = []
                if line != "" {
                    values = line.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
                    let str1 = (values[0])//FIRST COLUMN
                    let str2 = (values[1])//SECOND COLUMN
                    let db1 = NumberFormatter().number(from: str1)?.doubleValue
                    self.ar1.append(db1!)
                    let db2 = NumberFormatter().number(from: str2)?.doubleValue
                    self.ar2.append(db2!)

                }

            }

        }

    }//end of request

  sleep(3) // This delay sends data to MAIN, Otherwise NOT

  let dta = [self.ar1, self.ar2]

  completion(dta)

   }

  func httpGet(_ request: URLRequest!, callback: @escaping (String, String?) -> Void) {
     let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            callback("", error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:
                String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)!
            callback(result as String, nil)
        }
      })
      task.resume()
   }
```

}
      --------Web Class--------

```
-------Call In Class--------
 Web().getData (str:   "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f6j7w7zeqaavzqw/s02.txt?dl=0")
        {
        (result: [[Double]]) in

            let x = result[0]
            let y = result[1]
 }
-------Call In Class--------
```

Essentially, I am trying to access my variable "ar1" at a certain point in my code but I cannot. I am trying to return the value too but it returns NULL at that point.

What is wrong here ?

I tried like the below code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Web {
    var ar1 = [Double]()
    var ar2 = [Double]()

    func getData(str: String) -> [Double] {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: str)!)
      httpGet(request as URLRequest!){
            (data, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "Error")
            } else {
                let delimiter = "\t"
                let lines:[String] = data.components(separatedBy:     CharacterSet.newlines) as [String]

                for line in lines {           
                    var values:[String] = []
                    if line != "" {
                        values = line.components(separatedBy: delimiter)
                         let str1 = (values[0])//FIRST COLUMN
                        let str2 = (values[1])//SECOND COLUMN
                       let db1 = NumberFormatter().number(from: str1)?.doubleValue
                        self.ar1.append(db1!)
                        let db2 = NumberFormatter().number(from: str2)?.doubleValue
                        self.ar2.append(db2!)
                    }
                }
            dump (self.ar1) // "ar1" accessible HERE (returns all elements)
        }
    }//end of request
        //BUT I WANT TO RETURN "ar1" HERE !
       // So that I can use it in my MAIN class
        dump (self.ar1) // "ar1" not accessible here (returns ZERO elements)
        return self.ar1
    }
        func httpGet(_ request: URLRequest!, callback: @escaping (String, String?) -> Void) {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                callback("", error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                let result = NSString(data: data!, encoding:
                    String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)!
                callback(result as String, nil)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
}
    }
```

Comment: You probably can't use copyrighted content with all rights reserved on StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are returning the `ar1` from the return statement of your method whereas the value to `ar1` is being set in Aysnchronous callback completion handler. You should use the completion handler block where you are trying to access the value of `ar1`. HTTPGet function is running in Async mode and value in `ar1` is set in the callback handler block.

Let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: your return statement returns the value early while HTTP request is still receiving the response from server. You need to change the function `getData` so that it uses a completion handler block. You also need to change the code where you are currently calling `getData` so that you write the logic of using the value of `ar1` within the completion handler callback.   https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/